# How to Show API data on React-Select

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

So, I'm trying to show an Amazon country API to my React-Select component and I've tried to do this in many different ways, but I would only get as result a blank page or a white list on my Select component

The code below has only the Axios method to call the API.

What Should I do so I can show the API data on the Select component?

Here's my Form.jsx component:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Select from 'react-select';
import Axios from 'axios';


function Forms() {

  const [countries, setCountry] = useState([])

    Axios.get(`https://amazon-api.sellead.com/country`)
      .then(res => {
        const countries = res.data;
        console.log(countries)
      })

  return (
      <Form>
      <Row className="mb-3">
        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridEmail">
          <Form.Control type="text" name = "name"   placeholder="Nome" />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridPassword">
          <Form.Control type="email" name = "email" placeholder="E-mail" />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridPassword">
          <Form.Control type="text" name = "cpf" placeholder="CPF" />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridPassword">
          <Form.Control type="text" name = "tel" placeholder="Telefone" />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Label>País</Form.Label>
        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridPassword">

        <Select 

         />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Label>Cidade</Form.Label>
        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridPassword"> <br/>
        <Select
         
        />
        </Form.Group>

      <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
        Enviar
      </Button>


      </Row>
    </Form>
  );
}
export default Forms;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Hey, First of all, you have to understand that you have to store that data somewhere, The data that you received from API.
- Once you store it all you need is just update that in `useState([])`. That you created.
- Now this API you are calling must be called once only so all we need is `useEffect()` hook with `[]` an empty array as a dependency so it will only call once the function that is handling API, on initial render.
- Once you have data then just loop through it using the map function and render the options.
- Here is code.

**App.js**

```js
import "./styles.css";
import Forms from "./Forms.js";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Forms />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Forms.js**

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Select from "react-select";
import Axios from "axios";
function Forms() {
  // creating an useState for setting country list received from api
  const [countriesList, setCountriesLits] = useState([]);
  //async funtion that handling api
  const getCountries = async () => {
    let contries = []; // to store api data
    const countryRes = await Axios.get(
      `https://amazon-api.sellead.com/country`
    );
    countryRes.data.forEach((data) => {
      contries.push(data.name);
    });
    // updating state
    setCountriesLits(contries);
  };
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    alert(e.target.value);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getCountries();
  }, []);
  return (
    <Form>
      <Row className="mb-3">
        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridEmail">
          <Form.Control type="text" name="name" placeholder="Nome" />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridPassword">
          <Form.Control type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridPassword">
          <Form.Control type="text" name="cpf" placeholder="CPF" />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridPassword">
          <Form.Control type="text" name="tel" placeholder="Telefone" />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Label>País</Form.Label>
        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridPassword">
          <select onChange={handleChange}>
            {/* rendering option from the state countriesList  */}
            {countriesList.map((data, i) => (
              <option key={i} value={data}>
                {data}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Label>Cidade</Form.Label>
        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridPassword">
          {" "}
          <br />
          <Select />
        </Form.Group>

        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
          Enviar
        </Button>
      </Row>
    </Form>
  );
}
export default Forms;
```

You can also visit the working code here on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-buck-uzlr0m?file=/src/Forms.js:0-2259)
Below is the output:
[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

All you're doing is logging the data to the console (and shadowing a variable):

```
const countries = res.data;
console.log(countries)
```

If the data needs to be set in state, set it in state (and you don't need the local variable at all):

```
setCountry(res.data);
```

You've also removed the prop from your `<Select>` component.  Clearly you'll need that back:

```
<Select options={countries} />
```

---

As an aside... Names matter.  There is a pluralization inconsistency here:

```
const [countries, setCountry] = useState([])
```

It's best to keep your names consistent and meaningful, otherwise you end up confusing yourself when you try to use the data.  Since this is an array of values, maintain pluralization:

```
const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
```